# Consider the LPP $ \ Ax \leq b , \ \ x \geq 0 \ $ having $ \ infeasible \ $ solution and $ b \geq 0 \ $.

Tags: linear-programming

Consider the LPP $ \ Ax \leq b , \ \  x \geq 0 \ $ having $ \ infeasible \ $ solution  and $ b \geq 0 \ $.

We then start $ Phase \ I $ of the Simplex method by working with an Auxiliary problem in the following form:

$ Max \ \ -x_0 \\ Subject \ \ to \ \ [-1  \ | \  A ] \begin{bmatrix}x_0 \\ x \end{bmatrix} \leq b , \ \ x_0, x \geq 0 , .........(1) $

Then ,

(i)   Write the Dual of the problem $ \  (1) \ $

(ii)  Give reasons why $ \ infeasible \ $ solution to the Original problem implies there exists $ \ y , \ \ with \ \ A^T y \geq 0 , \ \ y \geq 0 \ \ and \ \ b \cdot y <0 \ $.

**Answer:**

(i)

The Dual  of $ \ (1) \ $ can be written as

$ Min \ \ b^T y    \\ \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ A^T \end{bmatrix} \ y \geq  \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \\ ... \end{bmatrix} \ $

**Am I Right ?**

**How can I solve the part (ii) ?**

Comment: I don't see why you have $$[-1 \mid A ] \begin{bmatrix}x_0 \\ x \end{bmatrix} \leq b.$$  It's said $Ax \le b, x,x_0\ge0$